# Laravel .htaccess cycling issue

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

Can anyone help me with the .htaccess issue? 
Now I see cycling error.

1. I've deleted .htaccess at /public folder
2. Changed .htaccess in root folder due to SEO requirements (www, https) and added from public

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ public/%1 [L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```